# Dojango/Dijit widgets

Tags: django, dojo, dijit.form

Can you add to dijit widgets that dojango creates without having to totally overwite them.

*(I ask because I want to add JS triggers [onChange, onClick] to some widgets)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no need to overwrite the widget. Use [dojo.connect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/connect.html) in your template to connect the widget event to your desired Javascript.

i.e.

```
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('id_field'),'onChange',
            function(){
                //do something
        });
```

Or if you are using dojango [forms integration](https://github.com/klipstein/dojango/wiki/Formintegration) and want to define the trigger with rest of the form.
i.e.

```
from dojango.forms import *
my_field = DateField(
    required=True, 
    help_text="Enter a valid date!", 
    widget=DateInput(
        attrs={
            'invalidMessage': 'The date is invalid!', 
            'class': 'customClass'
            'onClick': 'yourFunction()'
        }
    ))
```

Comment: I ended up using your second option a couple of weeks back. The only thing is you have to declare all the options again that are automatically created if you stuck with the default model (e.g. require=..., regex=..., etc.) I can get dojo.connect to work for some reason (I think because a lot of my stuff is AJAX) so everthing ends up declarative. Never mind!